# Backing up a database from MySQL 4 / 5 and restoring it to MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've done this once. But upon doing it again, the restored database does not have any tables.

Using MySQL Administrator, running on Windows 7, 32-bit, I created a backup file (.sql) of my database with the following steps:

Backup -> New Project -> Selected a schemata, and then created the backup. I did no fiddling around with the advanced options.

[image]

Now, I tried to restore it to my database server, running MySQL 5.6.12, on a Windows 7, 64-bit. I used MySQL Workbench to Restore the .sql file. It ran fine. No errors, no problems.

It's just that when I open up the restored database later, it has nothing in it.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please take a look in the backup file. Does it contain only meta data or actual records too? It sounds like you did not export your actual data but just the schema structure.

Comment: How do I do that? It's a .sql file, btw. Can't open it in Notepad++, says it is too large, if that means anything.

Comment: How large is too large? WB can open files like 150MB in size.